# Capacitor / Ionic: shall I remove the config.xml file

Tags: capacitor, ionic5

Since Capacitor is now working with [gradle](https://gradle.org/) directly, shall I safely remove the `config.xml` file from my capacitor / ionic project ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can remove the `config.xml` on the root of your project.
Capacitor uses `capacitor.config.json` (or .ts/.js) instead of the `config.xml`.

If you have Cordova's plugin preferences in the `config.xml`, Capacitor should have prompted you to move them to the capacitor config file when you ran `npx cap init`.